# php json decode object with array of multiple objects

Tags: php, json

I am unable to get values of array of this json... how can i have all these values seperately!!

```
{
    "id": "jai",
    "pwd": "123",
    "user": [
        {
            "fname": "jai",
            "lname": "gupta"
        },
        {
            "fname": "sameer",
            "lname": "seth"
        }
    ],
    "college": "vit"
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I am able to get all values except array. i want to store all users information to db. that's i want to do with this json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myArray = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($myArray['id']);
var_dump($myArray['user'][0]['fname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access each "value" by accessing regular php array key value pairs.

```
$jsonn = '{"id":"jai","pwd":"123","user":[{"fname":"jai","lname":"gupta"},{"fname":"sameer","lname":"seth"}],"college":"vit"}';
$new = json_decode($jsonn, true);

$id = $new['id'];
$user = $new['user'];
..... and so on.
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: use `assoc` parameter when docode the json if you want to access with key index.

Comment: @check missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can decode these values from json to object.

```
$result = json_decode('{"id":"jai","pwd":"123","user":[{"fname":"jai","lname":"gupta"},{"fname":"sameer","lname":"seth"}],"college":"vit"}');
```

and acccess like below:

```
$result->id; 
$result->pwd;
```